# Send email from FirefoxOS app with content

Tags: firefox-os, webintents

I'm trying to send an email from a FirefoxOS App to share content generated by it.

Currently I'm using:

```
var createEmail = new MozActivity({
  name: "new",
  data: {
    type : "mail",
  }
});
```

But I haven't been able to find any way of appending or attaching content to this email

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to @sebasmagri answer I learnt that the "mailto" URI accepts many more fields than I knew about. Specially interesting is the body and subject:

```
mailto:someone@example.com?
cc=someone_else@example.com
&subject=This%20is%20the%20subject
&body=This%20is%20the%20body
```

This allows me to set the different parts of the email as I wanted to.

The final code looks like:

```
var body = encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(event.target.result));
var createEmail = new MozActivity({
  name: "new",
  data: {
    type : "mail",
    url: "mailto:?subject=FiREST%20Request&body=" + body,
  }
});
```

Comment: Have you got some link for mailto paramters ?

Comment: what if i want to add an attachment?

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you can set attachments through `data.blobs` and `data.filenames`, and misc content (to, subject, content) through `data.URI`.

Detauls about the mailto: syntax can be found in the [MDN entry on Email links](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Email_links).

Regards,

**Edit May 2014**

As the mail app was refactored, I've dropped the old broken [code link](https://github.com/mozilla-b2g/gaia/blob/master/apps/email/js/mail-app.js#L279) in favour of MDN docs.

Comment: Yes, this code also includes a reference to set the body. I'll see if I can make it work with any of the two options, although I don't really want to use an attachment. Thanks anyway.